# AWS EMR - There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memory, mapreduce, emr

I am running a MapReduce job on AWS EMR. The map job completes except for one file that is very large. I get the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000611280000, 1521483776, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1521483776 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

It seems to be a memory issue. I've modified my configuration json file to have added (a lot more than required) memory:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "hadoop-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
           "HADOOP_DATANODE_HEAPSIZE": "10240",
           "HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS": "-XX:GCTimeRatio=19",
           "HADOOP_HEAPSIZE": "11264",
           "HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS": "-Xmx10240M"
       }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Classification": "mapred-site",
    "Properties": {
      "mapreduce.map.memory.mb": "24576",
      "mapreduce.map.java.opts": "-Xmx19200M",
      "mapred.child.java.opts": "-Xmx4096M",
      "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb": "15360",
      "mapreduce.reduce.java.opts": "-Xmx10240M",
      "mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks": "1",
      "mapreduce.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb": "25600",
      "yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb": "25600"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "hive-env",
    "Properties": {}
  },
  {
    "Classification": "hive-site",
    "Properties": {}
  }
]
```

However, I keep on getting the issue. As you can see, I have added mapred.child.java.opts as many suggest online, but I've had no luck. What else can I try?

Much appreciated.

Comment: These are a lot of different changes impacting multiple memory settings of multiple processes. Is this error coming from a map task attempt (thus found in a container log)?

Comment: Yes, map task from the looks of it.

Comment: What instance type are you using for slaves?

Comment: I have custom specs, as you can see from my configuration json file.

Comment: Yes, but knowing the instance type helps me understand whole system memory usage and OS requirements.

Comment: --instance-type m3.xlarge. Thanks.

Comment: Also, as a test, my removing such really large files, the job completes.

Comment: Where is the config file?

Answer (score 3):

It appears your configuration is exceeding the physical memory bounds of the server. The m3.xl only physically has 15G and by default the safe amount of memory to allocate to a container is 11.5G (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html).

So for the m3.xl the largest you can set mapreduce.map.java.opts is -Xmx9216 with mapreduce.map.memory.mb at 11520 (the opts should always be less than total map memory, usually around 80%).   These are the properties that impact the map task memory size. If the map task needs more memory in order to process the larger files, then a larger instance type will need to be used.

I recommend not making other memory property changes unless those processes are needing such tuning specifically.